# unable to access directory content from host to minikube cluster pod

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Since few days I am trying to get  below scenario working in minikube installed in linux RHEL. but unable to get that working.
I have some config files and log directory which i want to provide to application running in pod and read generated files and logs files .

I am using  PersistentVolume  here , persistent volumes are getting created and bound as as well , same as PersistentVolume which looks fine . but when when my both pods start they are able to share data between them using directory that I have configured in deployment but that data is not visible to me in the directory hosted as PersistentVolume.Nor my config files are available inside pod

---

as per my research that there mapping between host directory and minikube  directory is required
which I tried while restarting minikube cluster by using following command. but it seems its not working as my mapped directory inside minikube not showing content.

minikube start --mount-string="/home/tntuser/tnt-volumne:/mnt/tnt-volume"

Below are my configuration

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: app-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 500Mi
  volumeMode: Filesystem # Mount volume into Pod as a directory.
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: "/mnt/app-volume" # Path to the directory this PV refers to.
  nodeAffinity: # nodeAffinity is required when using local volumes.
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - minikube # node-hostname
---


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: app-pvc
spec:
  volumeName: app-volume
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-deployment
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-docker-core
          image: 6767.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app-core:1.2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: external_configuration_path
              value: "/usr/local/tomcat/ext-configuration"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/usr/local/tomcat/logs"
              name: task-app-volume
              subPath: logs
            - mountPath: "/usr/local/tomcat/data"
              name: task-app-volume
              subPath: data
            - mountPath: "/usr/local/tomcat/ext-configuration"
              name: task-app-volume
              subPath: ext-configuration
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8443 # The port that the container is running on in the cluster
      volumes:
        - name: task-app-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pvc
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: awsdockerreg

---

apiVersion: v1 # Kubernetes API version
kind: Service # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata: # Metadata of the resource kind we are creating
  name: app-k8s-internal-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: app-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8443 # The port that the service is running on in the cluster
      targetPort: 8443 # The port exposed by the service
      nodePort: 30002
  type: LoadBalancer # type of the service.
    ---
```

below are pv and pvc  status details

```
  $ kubectl get pv
    NAME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM             STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
    app-volume   500Mi      RWO            Delete           Bound    default/app-pvc   local-storage            21
```

---

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS   VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
app-pvc   Bound    app-volume   500Mi      RWO            local-storage   22m
```

Answer (score 0):

I explored and found out that there are couple of steps that needs to be done

1. Mount host machine directory to minikube cluster environment using below command.

> minikube start --mount
> --mount-string="$HOME/app-volume:/src/app-volume"

Point to be noted I changed command a bit and the mounted path to /src/ from mnt

2. Then created persistent volume using the mounted directory inside minikube environment.I used local volume using below yml of PV and PVC.

I am now able to access the content of host directory inside my pod.

```
  ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: app-volume
      labels:
        type: local
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      capacity:
        storage: 500Mi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      hostPath:
        path: /src/app-volume
      persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    
    ---
    
    
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: app-pvc
      namespace: default
    spec:
      volumeName: app-volume
      storageClassName: manual
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 500Mi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
    
    ---
```